# How to return multiple values into a label with sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

There is a similar question that is unanswered on stackoverflow, but I believe I am very close to solving it. But basically, my sql statement returns more than one value, but only a single value is displayed in the label whereas it should be 4 or 5 values.

```
  protected void btnPopulate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strings.settings.connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM dbo.MDRMASTER WHERE MASTERPID = @MASTERPID",con);
       command.Parameters.Add("@MASTERPID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMASTERID.Text;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read()) 
        {
            string ID = dr["ID"].ToString();
            lblIDs.Text = ID;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your first step should have been to set a breakpoint on lblIDs.Text = ID;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting the label's Text each time through the loop. You could simply change:

```
lblIDs.Text = ID;
```

to:

```
lblIDs.Text += ID + " ";
```

And basically populate the label with a space-delimited list.

Also, as a general best-practices programming hint: You are coupling your UI code to your data access code VERY tightly in this example. You should look into MVC, Presenter and several other options to avoid tight coupling. Here's an [article for starters](http://aspalliance.com/1360_Decoupling_Business_Logic_Layer_from_the_User_Interface_Layer_using_C).

Comment: But make sure you do `lblIDs.Text = string.Empty` before starting the loop, to clear out any previous value.

Answer (score 5):

You mean something like this?

```
var ids = List<string>();
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    ids.Add(dr["ID"].ToString());            
}
lblIDs.Text = String.Join(", ", ids);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the text with each step of `dr.Read()`

Try the following

```
var text = new StringBuilder();
while (dr.Read()) 
{
    text.Append(dr["ID"].ToString());
}

lblIDs.Text = text.ToString();
```